# /etc/fstab/ rw option is being ignored for mircosd card partition in ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, fstab, fat

I have ArchLiinux `Linux comp001 3.18.7-1-ARCH #1 PREEMPT Wed Feb 11 11:38:34 MST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux` for Arm installed on rPi and here is my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
#
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot       vfat    defaults            0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p3  /mnt/data   vfat    noexec,rw,noatime,user,umask=022        0       2
```

Partition `/dev/mmcblkop3` (microsd card fat32 partition) is mounted on `mnt/data` with `rw` options, but if I list `/mnt` directory, I get:

```
total 20
 4 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Sep 18 13:27 .
 4 drwxr-xr-x 18 root root  4096 Jan  9 11:08 ..
12 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 12288 Jan  1  1970 data
```

Why there is not write permission bit set on `data`?

Comment: @garethTheRed, Ok, another quemment (question/comment): The files and directories inside data inherit permissions from /etc/fstab umask option, as I understand. Now, data directory is shared across LAN via samba server. I must limit user's operation inside data (from MS Windows client) read. Is this done on linux layer or samba layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the `rw` option with the `umask`.

The `rw` option merely dictates that the partition is not mounted read-only.

The `umask` option dictates what permission that *not* set on files and directories.  Your current `umask` of `022` sets the permission bits to `755` which translates to `rwxr-xr-x`.  Change the `umask` to `000`, which should give you 777 or `rwxrwxrwx` permissions.

More info on `umask` is available on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me you have write permission **as root**.

Il you want write permission as pi user (or whoever )

```
 sudo chown pi /mnt/data
 sudo chmod g+w /mnt/data
```

The rw option in /etc/fstab allow proper user to write on filesystems. It is however seldom use. I once in a while mount a FS ro (read-only) due to migration or backup.